# como filtrar un array que tiene un valor distinto al que busco

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array

```
const eventos = [
  {status: 'pending', nombre: 'evento A'},
  {status: 'done', nombre: 'evento A'}
]
```

Quiero realizar un filtro, pero el usuario ingresa el valor en español como **pendiente**

Realice el siguiente filtro como

```
eventos.filter((evento) => evento.status.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchText))
```

No sé como hacer para que al ingresar el valor en español me lo vincule al valor que esta en ingles.

```
const labelStatus = {
      pendiente: 'pending',
      'en proceso': 'inProcess',
      realizado: 'done',
      cancelado: 'canceled',
    };
```

intente hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
evento.status.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(labelStatus[searchText])
```

Pero solo me devuelve cuando coincide por completo. No hay una forma de que por ejemplo si ingreso pendi ya me vaya retornando la data? y no tenga que si o si ingresar por completo **pendiente**

Comment: Qué vendría a ser `searchText`

Comment: El valor que buscaria, por ejemplo ingreso en un input "pendiente"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear esta función:

```
function mismoInicio(parcial, completa){
  if(parcial == '') return false;
  const er = new RegExp(`${parcial}.*`, 'i');
  let coincidencia = completa.match(er);
  return coincidencia == null ? false : coincidencia.length > 0;
}
```

Se le envían dos cadenas: `parcial` y `completa`. Si `parcial` es no vacía y se inicia como `completa`, entonces devolverá verdadero; en caso contrario, falso.

Ejemplos:

```
mismoInicio('', 'Hola Mundo'); //falso
mismoInicio('h', 'Hola Mundo'); //verdadero
mismoInicio('holA', 'Hola Mundo'); //verdadero
mismoInicio('hola, tú', 'Hola Mundo'); //falso
```

Lo que hace es

1. Verificar que la cadena sea no vacía
2. Si no es vacía, crear una expresión regular que verifique si `completa` es `parcial` con algunos caracteres añadidos (por eso el `.*` en la expresión regular). Esto lo hace ignorando las mayúsculas y minúsculas por la bandera 'i'.
3. Si la comparación es nula, o una lista vacía, devolver falso. Si hay coincidencias, devolver verdadero.

Sólo tienes que enviar esta función al filtro que creaste.